# Firebase - Count online users

Tags: javascript, firebase

I tried using [`presence`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html) to make it display the total connected users in an element. I can't really figure out how to make it work.

I also tried doing the following:

```js
    var dataUlist = new Firebase('https://<url>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected');
    dataUlist.on('value', function(snap) {
        console.log(snap);
    });
```

To tried to see if I could find anything useful in there, but I couldn't figure out how the data works.

Is there any way to accomplice what I am after? Fetch the total number of connected users and then echo it out in the console or to an element?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`.info/connected` will only return information about whether the current client is connected or not. In order to maintain a presence count, you'll need to create a counter by storing presence information for each user and  utilizing `setOnDisconnect()`. For example:

```js
var listRef = new Firebase("https://<url>.firebaseio.com/presence/");
var userRef = listRef.push();

// Add ourselves to presence list when online.
var presenceRef = new Firebase("https://<url>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected");
presenceRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  if (snap.val()) {
    // Remove ourselves when we disconnect.
    userRef.onDisconnect().remove();

    userRef.set(true);
  }
});

// Number of online users is the number of objects in the presence list.
listRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  console.log("# of online users = " + snap.numChildren());
});
```

Comment: Happy to help! My colleague pointed out two corrections:

1. The `onDisconnect()` call should be inside the `.info/connected` callback because we have to call it again when we reconnect.

2. We have a handy function called `numChildren()` to return the number of keys in an object!

I've updated the snippet above to reflect this.

Comment: Awesome guys, thank you soo much for the help, I am playing about with it now already - works a treat!

Comment: This seems a bit unscalable. Is there a way to just get an integer back?

Comment: Can you use .info/connected for child paths in order to get the number of users in a specific chat room? I.e. (https://<url>.firebaseio.com/<chat_room_name>/.info/connected) ??

Comment: No, .info/connected is only a valid path from the root.

Comment: @Anant -- it looks like your answer introduces a potential race condition. Luckily, an article you wrote helped point this out to me so I could remind you about it :-). In your very own words, "The onDisconnect() call is before the call to set() itself. This is to avoid a race condition where you set the user’s presence to true and the client disconnects before the onDisconnect() operation takes effect, leaving a ghost user". (from https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-06-17-howto-build-a-presence-system.html).

Comment: The problem is that in order for this to work one must pull down the ENTIRE list. So if you have a a user list of 10k, you'll need to pull down that entire list of 10k users which equals roughly 250kb. The only way I can think of to do this in a way that scales is to pull this list down on a server you control, and then deliver that number to the client.

Comment: I have wrote a module based on this idea for my own need. But this may help many others. Please check - https://gist.github.com/ajaxray/17d6ec5107d2f816cc8a284ce4d7242e

Answer (score 1):

Here is the the code from Anant formatted for Android

```
public void getDbCount() {

    Firebase listRef = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase-database>.firebaseio.com/presence/");
    final Firebase userRef = listRef.push();

    // Add ourselves to presence list when online.
    Firebase presenceRef = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase-database>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected");

    ValueEventListener myPresence = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            // Remove ourselves when we disconnect.
            userRef.onDisconnect().removeValue();
            userRef.setValue(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("DBCount", "The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };

    presenceRef.addValueEventListener(myPresence);

    // Number of online users is the number of objects in the presence list.
    ValueEventListener myList = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            // Remove ourselves when we disconnect.
            Log.i("DBCount", "# of online users = " + String.valueOf(snapshot.getChildrenCount()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("DBCount", "The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };

    listRef.addValueEventListener(myList);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question.

Comment: You are creating a section in your database to track presence. When added and executed it will push a key representing the current user onto the presence child. 

Firebase userRef = listRef.push();

When that user is disconnected, (Firebase object presenceRef) they will be removed from the list. 

userRef.onDisconnect().removeValue();

This code will display in the log the current number of users currently connected to the system, assuming everyone on the system executed this code. 

See https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-06-17-howto-build-a-presence-system.html for a more robust explanation.