# Number of online user (fireauth)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

How would I get the number of online users (and to know if a specific user is online)?

I'm using FireAuth.

Comment: Firebase does not track this for you.  You will have to write code to track it for yourself

Comment: You can read here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence how to implement it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase - Count online users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982215/firebase-count-online-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Doug commented: Firebase Authentication does not have a built in API to track how many users are currently online.

As Mattia commented: the common way to implement this within Firebase is by using the Realtime Database, which has some special handling for it. Read more in the Firebase documentation on [managing presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence). While I linked to the documentation for Android, the same functionality is available in the [Flutter library for the Firebase Realtime Database](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database).